# How to scrape messages from Telegram without having to get a bot in it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, telegram

How would I scrape messages from a Telegram channel without having to get my own bot in the channel in python?

Answer (score 4):

If the channel is public, you could go to: `https://t.me/s/{channelname}`

add a `/s` to see a version on the web without login. Some channels may not be available for this method.